# How to get MAX to return an array

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a 2D range of numbers in my sheet. I wish to have an array with the max of each row in an array for further calculation. However, MAX will only return a single number even when given a 2D array and using CSE.

I've thought about alternative ways of getting the array I require but all I can think of is helper columns or hard coding in testing each column to see if it is the max, none of which I wish to do.

So I would want {{1, 2}; {3, 5}} -> {2;5}

Answer (score 0):

**semi-automatic solution:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A39:A), {MAX(A39:B39); 
                              MAX(A40:B40);
                              MAX(A41:B41)}, ))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A39:B),
 "select "&REGEXREPLACE(JOIN("", 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A39:A), 
 "max(Col"&ROW(A39:A)-ROW(A39)+1&"),", ""))), 
 ".\z", "")&"")), "select Col2")
```

[image]